# How to handle ajax post data in spring boot

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot

I am using `jquery ui sortable` to reorder the page order in my project, however it seems I don't know how to properly handle this posted ajax data in spring boot.

jquery/ajax

```
$("table#pages tbody").sortable({
        items: "tr:not(.home)",
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
        update: function () {
            let ids = $("table#pages tbody").sortable("serialize");
            let url = "/admin/pages/reorder";

            // $.post(url, ids, function (data) {});
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: "post",
                data: ids,
                beforeSend: function () {
                },
                complete: function () {
                },
                success: function (response) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

So from the above, the `ids` variable should be an array integer called `id`, so I should get something like the following in my request handler = `int[] id` (singular id is correct)

So with above in mind, I tried to do this in my request handler method:

```
@PostMapping("reorder")
    public void reorder(int[] id) {
        int count = 1;
        Page page;
        for (int pageId : id) {
            page = pageRepo.getOne(pageId);
            page.setSorting(count);
            pageRepo.save(page);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

However using breakpoints I can see that `id` is actually `null`, so the request handler is clearly not getting the sent ajax data.

The error I get in chrome is:

```
error: "Internal Server Error"
```

I tried adding `@RequestBody` to the method parameter like so:

```
public void reorder(@RequestBody int[] id) {...
```

However in that case it doesn't even hit the breakpoint within the method at all and I get the following error in chrome:

```
error: "Unsupported Media Type"
```

If I don't manually set content type, I get the following request payload

The request payload:

```
id[]=29&id[]=3
```

content type:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

I can set content type to json, however I still get an error and I never had to do that in other technologies so I doubt that's the problem.

Comment: use **public void reorder(@RequestBody List id)** please let me know if this is working

Comment: Your AJAX call isn't setting the media type at all.

Comment: @HasnainAliBohra and how do i change `for (int pageId : id) {` ? I need the id to be an int. I tried List<Integer> but I sitll have the same problem.
`

Comment: @chrylis never had to manually set it using 2 other technologies (php and asp), I am basically copying the ajax from there and comparing. What should I set it to?

Comment: In your chrome dev tool, check the request body and paste here, it will help while answering.

Comment: @PratapiHemantPatel with RequestBody ?

Comment: From what you're showing, presumably `application/json`. You don't *strictly* have to do it with Spring, either, but it's doing automatic content negotiation for you (you can also send that POST method XML, for instance), so you need to tell it what format to use.

Comment: @chrylis ok how to handle json data in this instance? If I set content to json I get this error: `message: "JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'id': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')↵ at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 4]"`

Comment: I suggest you start by using your browsers developer tools to examine the actual POST payload, so you know for sure what is actually being posted by that AJAX call. Please edit question and show payload (request body) and value of `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the payload is `id[]=29&id[]=3`, then you need

```
public void reorder(@RequestParam("id[]") int[] id) {
```

since `id[]` is a non-standard query-parameter name that cannot be derived from the `id` method parameter name.

Comment: This actually works! The db data is changed, however I still get an annoying error in the console: `Error resolving template [admin/pages/reorder], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers"` - can I get rid of that? It is not a deal breaker but I'd really prefer not to have any crap in the console.

Comment: I guess I should be returning something which I am not? I tried returning the view but I still get an error (even though the view does exist) - n error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/admin/pages/index.html]")"

Comment: This is form encoding, not JSON.

Comment: @chrylis Assuming you're responding to the comments, not my answer, OP fixed the "template not found" error by adding `@ResponseBody` (not `@RequestBody`), because otherwise Spring MVC defaults to a view named after the URL, i.e. `reorder`, when no value identifying a view is returned. With `@ResponseBody`, and no return value, an empty payload is sent back.

Comment: I was commenting on the whole package, since the OP was apparently intending to use JSON but wasn't, and Spring's automatic support can handle multi-valued parameters (though `List<Integer>` would be more usual).